# jQuery UI working in Firefox, but not in Chrome & Safari?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, browser, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm using jQuery UI, specifically Datepicker and Autocomplete, as follows:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
$("#note_date").datepicker({ 
    maxDate: 0,
});

$("#note_name").autocomplete({
    source: ["1", "2"],
    select: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

They work fine in Firefox 3.6.8, but don't work at all in Google Chrome 5.0.375.126 and Safari 5.0 (6533.16). I thought jQuery UI stuff was supposed to work in these browsers? What could be causing them not to work? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the jquery-min.js script as well. If you right click your page in Chrome and choose inspector, you will see the errors that is happening. The following should work (all I did is added the jquery-min.js and let the javascript be loaded at the end, after the DOM been added)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="note_date"></div>
<div id="note_name"></div>
<script>
$("#note_date").datepicker({ 
    maxDate: 0,
});

$("#note_name").autocomplete({
    source: ["1", "2"],
    select: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use both of these and they work in all modern browsers.

Please note that you have a comma in your **datepicker** method, it should be

```
$("#note_date").datepicker({ 
    maxDate: 0 // no trailing comma
});
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BEeGY/).

As for the Autocomplete, the setup looks OK to me. Are you using any other JS frameworks? If you have a live page, I may be able to help further.

M

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```